# Laravel boolean value return wrong data

Tags: php, laravel

I have table name `payments` in this table each row has column named `paid` which is boolean. When I try to get separate list of paid and unpaid rows based on this `paid` column it just return all rows regardless.

`Code`

**Get unpaid rows**

```
$purchases = Payment::wherePaid(false)
    ->where('employee_id', $user->id)
    ->orWhere('employer_id', $user->id)->with([
        'employer',
        'employee' => function($q) {
            $q->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
        },
        'template',
        'training',
        'contract',
    ])->get();
```

**Get paid rows**

```
$purchases = Payment::wherePaid(true)
    ->where('employee_id', $user->id)
    ->orWhere('employer_id', $user->id)->with([
        'employer',
        'employee' => function($q) {
            $q->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
        },
        'template',
        'training',
        'contract',
    ])->get();
```

`Model`

```
protected $casts = [
  'paid' => 'boolean',
];
```

In both queries I am getting array of 4 which is include 3 unpaid and 1 paid row.

## Update

`Schema`

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('employer_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('employee_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('template_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('contract_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('training_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('duration')->nullable();
        $table->string('amount');
        $table->boolean('paid')->default(false);
        $table->string('booking_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('invoice_no');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::table('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('employer_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('employee_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('template_id')->references('id')->on('contract_templates')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('contract_id')->references('id')->on('contracts')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('training_id')->references('id')->on('trainings')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Comment: You should post table schema too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I think your issue is that you are asking for `paid = false` AND `employee_id = ID` OR `employer_id = ID`. I think MySQL is thinking:

```
(paid = false AND employee_id = ID) OR (employer_id = ID)
```

So, try this query instead:

```php
$purchases = Payment::wherePaid((false or true))
    ->where(function ($query) use ($user) {
        return $query->where('employee_id', $user->id)
            ->orWhere('employer_id', $user->id)
    })
    ->with([
        'employer',
        'employee' => function($query) {
            return $query->select(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
        },
        'template',
        'training',
        'contract',
    ])
    ->get();
```

That will change the query to:

```
(paid = false or true) AND (employee_id = ID OR employer_id = ID)
```

Comment: seems to be working! :) but isn't strange it assume true or false is based on user while i provided it on Payment model `Payment::wherePaid((false or true))` ?

Comment: you need to input that, of course! I just wrote both, you need to decide when to use what